# корзина не очищается

Tags: symfony2, ecommerce, sylius, платежи

после совершения покупки (`state` **order** изменяется с `cart` на `pending`)
покупка отображется в админке как новая, но корзина не очищается.
при попытке очистить корзину

```
    $cartProvider = $this->container->get('sylius.cart_provider');
    $cart = $cartProvider->getCart();
    $eventDispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::CART_CLEAR_INITIALIZE, new CartEvent($cart));
    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::CART_CLEAR_COMPLETED,  new FlashEvent());
    return JsonResponse::create(true);
```

платеж помещается в удаленные, и больше не отображается в админке

```
 $cartProvider = $this->container->get('sylius.cart_provider');
 /* @var $order \Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Order */
 $order = $cartProvider->getCart();
 $manager =  $this->container->get('sylius.manager.order');
 $order->clearItems(); //удаление элементов корзины
 $order->clearAdjustments(); //очистка суммы
 $manager->persist($order);
 $manager->flush();
```

платеж отображается в новых, но без товаров

кто работал с Sylius, как чтобы после совершения покупки пользователем, его корзина стала пустой?

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему удалением **id_card** из сессии
**$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_sylius.cart_id']**